# How to provide Public API for vue.js application?

Tags: api, vue.js, public

I need to provide user Public API which he can use to control my vue.js plugin from outside

```
<div id='app'></div>
```

For example,

```
myApi.doThing()
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was very simple:

**User script**

```
let userButton = document.querySelector('.user-button');

userButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  myApi.open()
});
```

**main.js in Vue application**

```
import App from './App.vue';

window.myApi= new function () {
  this.doThing = function() {
    App.methods.methodName();
  }
};
```